# I start programming in j2me, how to get the maximum compatibility with every cellphone?

Tags: java-me

I am a newbie to J2me. I am programming a Java program to recognise QRs.

The specifications of the projects include the compatibility with most of cellphones. For example, Nokia with Symbian, iPhone or HTC with windows mobile.

I have started downloading, JDK, WTK, eclipse and MTJ.

Any other advice would be of help.

To do this, I will need to provide a different distro for every commercial mark? or OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run J2ME applications on iPhone or Android.

iPhone apps are written in Objective-C, and Android apps are written in regular Java (almost). Don't know about the Symbian case (but that probably runs J2ME just fine).

If you want a high degree of code-reuse, I strongly advice you to try to do the application web-based, preferably executed in the browser, or with a minimal OS-specific implementation of a front-end.